# Moving the Gardener/Panda 'in a straight line' in Takenoko

Tags: takenoko

The rules in Takenoko state that the Panda/Gardener can move in a straight line as far as they like, but not over gaps between tiles.

In practice this means that the movement of the Panda/Gardener is hardly restricted. Would it be possible to restrict the movements of other players by placing the Gardener/Panda right on the edge of a tile on the edge of the map, thus reducing the available angles of movement for the next person to move the Panda/Gardener?

I have assumed that movements are taken from the position of the Panda/Gardener piece, not the centre of the tile he is in. I have also assumed that the angle that the Panda/Gardener moves does not have to be congruent with any of the edges of the segment.

Answer (score 10):

The "straight line" is between tiles, not the precise position of the gardener. This isn't a miniatures wargame like Warhammer 40k; it's a tile-based abstract Euro.

Here are the diagrams of what a "straight line" means from the rulebook:

[image: Moving the Gardener]
[image: Moving the Panda]

As you can see, the "straight line" limitation simply means that movement must be across shared edges of tiles, in a straight line, rather than "around the bend".

Comment: Thank you. Would you say that a move is legal if a straight line can be drawn from one or more points in the starting segment to one or more points in the destination segment?

Comment: No. I would say that each tile is a distinct entity. Basically, you draw a line from the center of one tile to the center of another tile, and that line can only pass through the "edges" between the tiles like in the pictures. There's no positioning _within_ a tile. You're either on the tile or you're not.

Comment: OK. Hmm, what if the line between the centre of two tiles took you along the outside edge of a tile which was itself on the edge of the map? Would that move be permitted or not?

Comment: You are really overthinking it. The token can move any number of "spaces" but can not change direction. Moving one "space" involves crossing the line between tiles. If they were squares, it would be orthogonal directions only.

Comment: Do you mean that all moves must be perpendicular to an edge of the segment that they started in?

Comment: See @ikegami's picture. In that picture, the entire list of legal moves for a gardener/panda are: A<->B. A<->C. B<->C. B<->D. A<->D. C<->E.  I don't know how to explain it any clearer. It's like moving spaces in a boardgame; you can't move along the edge in Candyland, nor can you move along the edge in Takenoko. (edit: missed one)

Comment: It seems that we are stuck with having to make a choice about how to interpret the rule. I understand what you are saying; a straight line move is one that is perpendicular to the edges of segments. This makes moving the gardener/panda a little bit like chess. Another interpretation is that you take _any_ straight line from the centre of the tile that the figure occupies. This makes more sense to me as there is no physical reason why the movement of the figure would need to be limited by the shape of the "space".

Comment: How about this: The wording in the rulebook (in both places that describe this method of movement) says "straight line, any *number of plots* in the direction of his choice". This indicates that "one plot" is the unit of distance used for movement. And the only way to move "a number of plots" in any direction that makes sense is how myself and ikegami have described it.  If this still doesn't make sense to you, you should probably contact the game company rules representatives directly so they can give you a satisfactorily definitive answer.

Comment: Thank you Josh - you've made good arguments. I agree that unless anyone else has already done so and wants to share, an appeal to the 'official' rulemakers is the only way to finally resolve the matter.

Answer (score 5):

The Panda/Gardener are located on a tile, not the edge of one. They move from a tile to an adjacent tile, where an adjacent tile is one that shares a side with the current tile.

Moving in a straight line means that after moving to an adjacent tile, you can continue moving by exiting tiles on the side opposite of the one you entered.

For example, the Panda could move from tile A to tile B since they are adjacent. It could also move from A to C since A and C are on opposite sides of B.

```
    / \     / \     / \   
  /     \ /     \ /     \
 |   A===|===B===|==>C   |
 |       |       |       |
  \     / \     / \     / \
    \ /     \ /     \ /     \
     |   D   |       |   E   |
     |       |       |       |
      \     /         \     /
        \ /             \ /
```

You could move the panda from D to B, but that's as far as you can go since there is no tile on the opposite side of B. You cannot move to D to E because of the gap between them.

Comment: Could you move from A to E?

Comment: No. If you continue the arrow *in a straight line*, you won't end up in E. (B and E aren't on opposite sides of C.)

Comment: A straight line can be in _any_ direction - it sounds as if you mean a straight line _that is perpendicular to an edge of the starting segment_?

Comment: There are only six directions in which you can travel. Any line you create will necessarily be perpendicular to an edge.

Comment: Thank you - to finish off, why not join the discussion above with @Josh and I?

Comment: There's nothing to discuss.